# MySQL slow loading - Pagination

Tags: mysql, joomla

We are using the latest version of Joomla 3.6.5 and the latest version of J Directory

http://www.cmsjunkie.com/j-businessdirectory

and we are having a bit of a disagreement with the developers.

Our directory has grown over the last year and page loading is now very poor where we have more then 500+ entries per category. J directory are saying its because we have a large number of entries,

Please see below url that is loading slowing, we have around 1100 entries associated with this category.

http://www.shoppingonline.ie/category/clothes-shops-womens

but this should not make any difference right ? There are 1000's of websites online that have huge DB's and that display large amounts of results

See below an example of a classifieds website that shows 66,914 ads for "cars" in Ireland

donedeal.ie/all?words=cars&area=Ireland

So what I am saying to the developers is that it we should not be retrieving all the results only the results that show on the page - currently 20 and then pagination kicks in and you load the next 20 results etc etc.

Can you confirm this is the way it should work right ? Surely the example above of does not retrieve 66,914 as the performance would be very poor indeed if it did, and it currently loads very quickly.

---

Please see below response from dev.

You must have misunderstand the whole situation. 
We do not retrieve all the results at once. As you can see only 20 items are being retrieved at once. 
The issue is that mysql has to go through all 1000 results that match the search criteria order them by the order criteria and then get 20 results within the requested page window. 
That is causing the performance penalty. This is not a bug. This is a Mysql performance limitation. 
As you can see the search is performing well for fewer results and that proves there is no bug or coding issue. 
I hope we have clarified the situation now.
The sites that you are referring to must be using other database engines (paid database engines) or indexes like google that are more efficient.

Comment: It shouldn't be loading all records and then discarding ones not on the current page.  BUT it would be more useful if you can find the SQL statements that it is running and find out what is really happening in the background.

Comment: 1000 results (while far from ideal) is tiny for MySQL to process if written reasonably. However the checks for search criteria and ordering should be done on the database before retrieving the data to php. Often this involves dynamically generating the SQL. If the framework chosen cannot support this then it possibly is the wrong tool for the job.

Answer (score 0):

This load time is definitely gonna annoy customers. They don't appear to be limiting the number of results they are retrieving. The link you posted to your page looks like this and takes about 17 seconds to load:
http://www.shoppingonline.ie/category/clothes-shops-womens

If I click page # 2, it takes only 8.8 seconds to load (which is still terrible but better). Notice the url:
http://www.shoppingonline.ie/component/jbusinessdirectory/search/266?Itemid=101&controller=search&categorySearch=266&orderBy=packageOrder desc&limit=20&start=20

The &limit=20 is probably how your developers are telling your websites to retrieve a max of 20 rows from your database, whereas without that, it seems to be grabbing everything. They need to put the same limit on the home page.

It also seems like your traffic is being routed to doubleverify.com and then to your website. A tool like Google Analytics would track your web traffic after your user landed on your page, eliminating the need for them to get bounced all over the web. I'd sit down with your devs and ask them exactly how many websites the user gets bounced around to before landing on your actual page. That stuff is time consuming.

As far as your database, I've never used J Directory but almost all databases give you the ability to put indexes on your database fields. Indexing will greatly reduce the time it takes for database queries to complete.

Your devs also have a LOT of blank lines in their HTML, this is probably doubling or tripling the size of your web page which is not helping it to load quickly. They can still have a readable format without all the extra blank lines.

Comment: Hi Folks thanks so much for the feedback, please see above response from the dev of J Directory.

Comment: That is a salesmans canned answer. The sites listed in your website have nothing to do with slowing down your website. Also, this doesn't fix your problem. Mysql is capable of performig queries in milliseconds. They seem to have no interet in fixing this.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested that page. It is loading very very slow , taking 16.x seconds.
You needed to hire a expert freelancer which have done lot of work in website speed optimization.

Answer (score 0):

We had a [similar performance problem with Mosets Tree](http://www.itoctopus.com/mosets-tree-an-extremely-slow-unoptimized-joomla-extension) - the way to uncover the real problem is to check the MySQL slow query logs (this should be enabled in the `my.cnf` file). By the way, the fact that they are only displaying 20 records does not mean that they are retrieving just those 20 records. Also, that might not be the problem - the problem might be caused by some very complex queries and/or some queries without proper indexes.

Again, the key to get down to the bottom of the problem is through the slow query log. You can also enable the Joomla debug, and check how much time each query is taking.